# how to authenticate facebook login using graph api ios with ARC?

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, automatic-ref-counting

how to authenticate facebook login using graph api ios with ARC.
Have followed this link,
http://room214.com/best-practices/iphone-facebook-oauth-2-0-and-the-graph-api-a-tutorial-part-2

Comment: Please provide some more info like what issue you are facing in using graph API.

Comment: Rquirement is that I want to login to facebook through webview not safari,which is solved by the above tutorial which I have mentioned above.But issue is this is not using ARC,and If I am trying to use in ARC environment,then app is crashing.

Comment: Disable ARC for that class only. follow this to disable ARC in single file.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project